# Loop over checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a checkbox in each table row, and I would like to press the "Save" which will loop over each checkbox:
(if checked)-> enter to database that this student has attended
else ->enter to database that this student has not attended.

[image]

My PHP code:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" width="550px" style="text-align:center;">
    <th> Student ID </th>
    <th> First Name </th>
    <th> Last Name </th>
    <th> Class ID </th>
    <th> Attended </th>
<?php
    $classid = $_GET['classid'];

    $mysql_host='localhost';
    $mysql_user='root';
    $mysql_password='';
    $con = @mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);

    if(!$con){
        die('Failed to connect to the database');//if not successful
    }else{
        //echo "Successfully connected to MySQL!";//if successful
        if(@mysqli_select_db($con, 'application_database')){//selecting the database
            //echo '<br>'."Connected to the specified database!";
        }else{
            die('<br>'."Could not connect to the specified database!");
        }
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE class = '$classid'";
    $records=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($student=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$student['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['first_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['last_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['class']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'<input type="checkbox" name="attendedCB">'."</td>";
    }

    echo '<form>';
    echo 'Teacher ID: <input type="number" name=teacher_id>';
    echo '<button name="save" type="submit">Save Attendance</button>';
    echo '</form>';


?>
</table>
```

I have a "student_attendance" table in the db, so I want to add each student along with his/her "attended" checkbox status. Cheers :D

Comment: Make the checkbox an array `<input type="checkbox" name="attendedCB[]">` Then you can loop over `$_POST['attendedCB']`

Comment: RULE: All inputs have to exist INSIDE the `<form>...</form>`

Comment: Using the `@` error silencer just keeps you in that dark about your errors. While developing YOU NEED TO KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING WRONG

Comment: Yeah man, I am sorry that my ignorance triggered you :P, I am self-taught (still learning), so you gotta bear with me :)

Comment: But thanks a lot for these helpful advice

Comment: Inside your HTML Form, you don't have any Input element. The simple way without using JavaScript is to put your Input elements inside a HTML Form element and you have to determine the method of sending data to your target php page for treatment. Change also the `name="attendedCB"` to `name="attendedCB[]"`

Answer (score 1):

```
// loop per student
foreach ($_POST ['student'] as $student ) {
    extract($student) // extract array (lazy)
    // if they attended 
    if ( !empty ($attendedCB )) {
        // add them
        $query = "INSERT INTO your_table id,first,last,class,attendedCB VALUES($id, $first, $last, $attendedCB)";
        // then run that query or aggregate them all into one big one and run it
    }
}
```

Also, change the checkbox name to `student['attendedCB']` and this should work.

Comment: Hey man, I tried it, but I sure I messed it up.`foreach ($_POST ['student'] as $student ) {
     extract($student); // extract array (lazy)
     // if they attended 
     if (!empty($attendedCB)){
     // add them
     // $query = "INSERT INTO your_table id,first,last,class,attendedCB VALUES($id, $first, $last, $attendedCB)";
      echo "TEST".$student['id'];
     }else{
      echo "TEST22222".$student['id'];
     }
     }`

Comment: it is giving me these errors `(Notice: Undefined index: student in C:\xampp\htdocs\ApplicationDemo\fetch_students_add.php on line 136

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ApplicationDemo\fetch_students_add.php on line 136)`

Comment: Are you posting to the page?

Comment: Yeah, I mean just to make sure it works. When the person clicks a button, I want to save the entries to the db without leaving the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use id as value of check box by clicking that get the id value.
Based on the id value you can do operations(update, delete, edit)

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='attendedCB' value ='.$student["id"].'></td>";
```

Comment: There is a bit more to OP's issues... See my comments